# Attaching change() even listeners to select/dropdown dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm creating 3 dropdowns/select boxes on the fly and insert them in the DOM through .innerHTML.

I don't know the ID's of the dropdowns until I created them in Javascript.
To know which dropdowns have been created, I create an array where I store the ID's of the dropdowns I have created.

```
for(var i=0; i<course.books.length; i++)
{
  output+="<label for='book_"+course.books[i].id+"'>"+ course.books[i].name +"</label>";
  output+="<select id='variant"+course.books[i].id+"' name='book_"+course.books[i].id+"'>";
  output+="<option value='-'>-- Select one --</option>";
  for(var j=0; j<course.books[i].options.length; j++)
  {
      output+="<option value='"+course.books[i].options[j].id+"'>"+course.books[i].options[j].name+"</option>";
  }
  output+="</select>";
}
```

Now I have an array with 3 id's like:

- dropdown1
- dropdown2
- dropdown3

What I want to accomplish with Javascript (without using jQuery or another framework) is to loop over these 3 dropdowns and attach a change event listener to them.

When a user changes the selection in one of these dropdown, I want to call a function called `updatePrice` for example.

I'm a bit stuck on the dynamic adding of event listeners here.

Comment: dropdown = select ? please include the code you use to create these "dropdowns"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have added your code its straight forward and you can ignore my verbose answer !!!

```
output+="<select id='variant"+course.books[i].id+"' name='book_"+course.books[i].id+"'>";
```

could become :

```
output+="<select onchange="updatePrice(this)" id='variant"+course.books[i].id+"' name='book_"+course.books[i].id+"'>";
```

This will call the updatePrice function, passing the select list that changed

### However

IMO its far better ([from a performance point of view for a start](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml/10)) to create elements in the DOM using the DOM.

```
var newSelect = document.createElement("select");
newSelect.id = "selectlistid"; //add some attributes
newSelect.onchange = somethingChanged;  // call the somethingChanged function when a change is made

newSelect[newSelect.length] = new Option("One", "1", false, false); // add new option    
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newSelect); // myDiv is the container to hold the select list
```

Working example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/MStgq/2/

Comment: thanks, is it correct that .add(option, null) is not compatible with IE? I've read that the second parameter has to be omitted to get it to work in IE. In that case, is my first (longer) solution better and more compliant?

Comment: @Jorre I always prefer to use the DOM method of creating elements .. its faster when you do it a lot -> http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml/10

Comment: @Jorre also changed `add` to `appendChild`

Comment: and is it cross browser compatible?

Comment: @Jorre added a jsfiddle to the bottom to demo it - cross browser support added with `new Option` function call ...

Comment: Thanks for that. I've gone with your second method and re-wrote my code. Thanks a lot for pointing out that there's a better way to create dropdowns...

Answer (score 1):

You got the array already? Then you can do this:

```
function updatePrice()
{
     alert(this.id + " - " + this.selectedIndex);   
}

var list = ["dropdown1", "dropdown2"];
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
    document.getElementById(list[i]).onchange = updatePrice;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkLMT/3/

Comment: looks good! Is there a way to detect what select box has been changed in the function updatePrice?

Comment: Added a new fiddle, the `this` object refers to the SELECT that is changed.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work across browsers.
You'll want something like

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
   $("#"+list[i]).change(updatePrice);
}
```

in jquery.